# How to find source of a joomla page

Tags: css, web, joomla

Suppose I have a website , www.loirevalleywineries.com . This site is made in joomla . Now if I navigate to another page it only show the arguments with name and I am unable to find the source who created this view.

My question is how can I find the source of a specific item and edit its style ?

Comment: In the administrator section, look up what the page contains exactly. There may be articles, extensions, modules, plug-ins etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable the option **Preview Module Positions** in:

   **System** > **Global Configuration** > **Templates**
2. Add in your URL something like:

   yoursite.com/administrator/**?tp=1**
3. You can see the module positions and the content section.
4. In your administrator area you have two main options to show your content:

   A - Via **Menu Items.**

   B - Via **Modules.**

Just check your correct configuration.